# PHP For loop for slider only render if not empy

Tags: php, for-loop, is-empty

I am creating slider and getting images and link from theme options. Which is having input fileds for image url and link url.

Problem is when I set variable for the option and trying to get only fields which is set or not empty with below code it is not rendering anything, But when I write code without checking empty field it is rendering but empty slides too.

So if I have set only two images it is rendering with 5 slides with 3 empty.

My Code:

```
$slides = '<ul class="the-slider">';
for($s=1; $s<=5; $s++){

    $slide = $this->the_opt('slide'.$s.'_url_image');
    $slide_link = $this->the_opt('slide'.$s.'_link_image');
    $slide_name = basename($this->the_opt('slide'.$s.'_url_image'));
    $slide_alt = substr($slide_name, 0, strrpos($slide_name,'.'));

    if(!empty($slide)){
        $slides .= '<li><a href="'.$slide_link.'"><img src="'.$slide.'" alt="'.$slide_alt.'" title="'.$slide_alt.'" /></a></li>';
    } else {
        return '<div class="the-error">Set the slider...</div>';
    }
} // end for loop

$slides .= '</ul>';

return $slides;
```

So how can I get output of only set fields?

Comment: Okay if I remove else condition to render error message it is working fine.. May be because I am returning.. but than how I can display the message as well

Answer (score 0):

You are returning only `'<div class="the-error">Set the slider...</div>'` if any of the slides is empty.

try

```
$slides .= '<div class="the-error">Set the slider...</div>';
```

instead of

```
return '<div class="the-error">Set the slider...</div>';
```

You won't even need that else part, if you need to show only non empty slides and ignore others.

Comment: I have already tried this but than it is returning within the slide instead of only error

Comment: You are hard coding how many slides to display to 5 `for($s=1; $s<=5; $s++)`

Comment: if you want to display error message in place of empty slide wrap your error message in the `<li>` tag like this $slides .= '<li><div class="the-error">Set the slider...</div></li>';